# EPPlus Invalid Address Format Error

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

When trying to read an excel worksheet I receive the error **Invalid Address format TABLE_QUERY_FROM_MS_ACCESS_DATABASE[BACKORDERS]** It happens on this line...

```
 If package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count = 0 Then
```

Matter of fact, anytime I access the .Workbook I receive this error which is a complete show stopper for me right now. Now I've read the excel file (and I'm not an excel expert) but when I click on the **Formulas** tab, then I click on the **Name Manager** button, a dialog comes up with five columns. **"Name, Value, Refers To, Scope, Comment"** BackOrders has multiple entries and on all of the records under Refers To is the value **=Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database[BackOrders]**

When I click on the referring location I am brought to another Worksheet in the same Workbook and the column **BackOrders** is highlighted. Does anyone have any idea whatsoever how I can correct this?

Answer (score 5):

Your column name as a space in it. The bug is here: https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14779

A fast work around that worked for me was to just do the failing call twice like so:

```
var ws;
try{
    ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}catch( Exception ){
    ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}
```

In my simple case it sufficed to keep me going.

Comment: How are you using 'var ws' without initializing it first? You can't use uninitialized local variables AFAIK.

Comment: But your solution worked when I declared and initialized it inside the try/catch block. +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the real reason is that EPPlus cannot have a named range that has a scope of 'Workbook'.  You can use workbook-scoped names using the technique shown in [EPPlus - Named Range is not populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871976/epplus-named-range-is-not-populated/21894409), but to just look up a value given a field name, make sure the name is scoped to the sheet.