# EPPlus - Named Range is there but not working

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Similar to
[EPPlus - Named Range is not populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871976/epplus-named-range-is-not-populated)
In his case, his ranges were at the workbook level but he was looking at the worksheet level.
My EP code shows a count of 0 ranges at the workbook level and 15 at the sheet level, as it should be.
Opening the worksheet.Names shows all 15, with proper names.

Retrieve a range, and the formula is correct with
"OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$33, 0, Sheet1!_CurrentMonth, 1, 55 -Sheet1!_CurrentMonth)", but almost everything else returns an exception on evaluation.
It reports 1 column, which is incorrect.
And the 'FullAddress' looks correct with "'Sheet1'!_Fund1Projected", but 'FullAddressAbsolute' gives "$#REF!$-1"

Lastly, I'm using a template, xltm, to create a spreadsheet, xlsm.

```
        public static void CreateChart()
    {
        var excelFullPath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Excel\\Templates\\";
        var excelFileName = "LowCashBalanceChart.xlsm";
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(excelFullPath + excelFileName);
        if (newFile.Exists)
           newFile.Delete();
        FileInfo template = new FileInfo(excelFullPath + "Sample Chart.xltm");
        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile, template))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]; //xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(); 
            ExcelNamedRange namedRange;
            namedRange = xlPackage.Workbook.Names["_Fund1Projected"]; // fails, no ranges at the WB level
            namedRange = worksheet.Names["_Fund1Projected"]; // this one works               
            for (int rowIndex = namedRange.Start.Row; rowIndex <= namedRange.End.Row; rowIndex++)  // Exception on range.Start
            // 'namedRange.Start' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
            {
                for (int columnIndex = namedRange.Start.Column; columnIndex <= namedRange.End.Column; columnIndex++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = (rowIndex * 100 + columnIndex).ToString();

                }
            }

            xlPackage.Save();
        }
    }
```

I looked at the code on GitHub, but nothing stands out.
Tried it with the ranges at the workbook level as well with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I'll put answer here for anyone that may need it in the future.

I created a range for a 3x3 square.
Range1 = =Sheet1!$A$24:$C$26

I can write to that just fine. No exceptions.

But when we have ranges that have endpoints determined by values of other cells, it fails.

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$32, 0, Sheet1!_CurrentMonth, 1, 55 -Sheet1!_CurrentMonth)

The problem is that our named ranges are dynamic.
That’s why it was getting an exception.

The work-around is to not use dynamic ranges from EPPlus.
Just a little more C# code to handle the dynamic part instead of Excel handling it for you.